# What is this plant with a purple flower?

Tags: identification

I live in Victoria, in the Pacific North West (zone 8) and summer arrived here this week and the flowers pictured below started to bloom.  I'm new here.  Can anybody identify them?[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like some specifies of Arum lily. Is it growing in the wild or in a garden?

Comment: @David Liam Clayton In a garden.

Comment: This is one heck of a plant to find in one's garden.  Scary looking flower...seriously!  Grins!  Do you have cats?  This plant is seriously attractive and very poisonous to cats.

Comment: @stormy Unfortunately controlling where a cat goes is beyond my abilities.  Besides our own, whom I am happy  to simply get in at night, our yard is contested territory for some others.  No cat corpses so far though.  Apparently it's also toxic for dogs and we have one, but she ignores vegetable matter.

Comment: Ha ha ha...just good to know if you've got cats.  Hey, I am a little sensitized as we found we have 5 new kittens of our very own...from a feral that looked no older than 6 months.  I simply can't admit the other ferals, strays, free loaders from the neighborhood I feed (otherwise they'd eat more baby bunnies)...and the ditties I have indoors.  I have a sickness.  Grins.  Cats are actually attracted to lilies, they don't just happen to munch on a leaf.  And they would go off to die anyway.  Amazing plant to just show up in your garden.  What color are your hydrangeas?

Comment: @stormy Those hydrangeas are blue.  There's also an oak leaf and a climbing one.  We bought the house less than a year ago so we're still learning what's here.  The previous owners were avid gardeners and lived here from the mid-70s.  We're new to Victoria and its climate is different than the rest of Canada so there's much I've never seen before.

Comment: Victoria is maritime, like Seattle and Portland.  Very different than continental climates and weather.  I lived in the San Juan Islands right there in the sound...my mum was a border official in Sumas?  Blue Hydrangeas mean you've got a slightly acidic soil.  Excellent.  I'd be confused if they were pink.  I had to ask.  Are you able to contact the previous owners about their plants that are now your plants?  Probably not...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Dracunculus vulgaris, a tuberous perennial plant. You may not like it because as it matures, it absolutely stinks when it's ready to be pollinated. Sometimes grown in gardens for its novelty value, it has many common names, some of which are unmentionable here, but a fairly common one is Dragon's Arum or Dragon Lily. It is native to mediterranean areas. More info here http://www.tropicalbritain.co.uk/dracunculus-vulgaris.html

Comment: Vulgar Lily!  Beautiful purple but you know, I just knew this was gonna stink.  Good job Bamboo.  Victoria should be the same or less than Seattle, Al says it is 8?   Is there another zone map I don't know about, Bamboo?  Someone else just said they were in zone 10 I think it was UK...

Comment: You use Sunset zones or USDA zones over there Stormy - I have a book that classifies Europe and the UK by zone, but not sure the temperatures correspond with USDA numbers - most of the UK is Zone 8 as far as I can tell.

Comment: @stormy Victoria is listed as Zone 9 but in my opinion that's a stretch.  We're at the north end of it.   We're a wee bit cooler but noticably drier than Seattle.  But we're substantially cooler than both coastal Oregon and Northern California that I would consider Zone 9. As well. the zone lines get very close together up here. Personally  I would rather error on the conservative side and call us Zone 8.

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks for the identification.  I have to laugh because one of our most striking local species is another a member of the Araceaea family, Lysichiton americanus, or as we say here, skunk cabbage.  In the house I lived in up until last August, the ravine behind the house was full of skunk cabbage at this time of year.  Gorgeous, but stinky.

Comment: Oh delightful, surrounded by stinky plants!